# How can I redistribute gene intervals evenly spaced across a circle in R?

Tags: r, geometry

I have a different number of genes distributed across each of the 22 chromosome in humans, with each chromosome's position starting from 0 base pairs, and I am trying to find a way to distribute the gene intervals evenly across a circle, keeping the relative positions between each gene and the length of each gene, but recreating new positions so that the genes can be evenly spaced on each chromosome, and leaving a space in between each chromosome. This is an example of the data (the complete dataset includes all chromosomes):

```
df = structure(list(Chr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 17L, 20L, 22L, 22L), .Label = c("chr1", 
"chr2", "chr3", "chr4", "chr5", "chr6", "chr7", "chr8", "chr9", 
"chr10", "chr11", "chr12", "chr13", "chr14", "chr15", "chr16", 
"chr17", "chr18", "chr19", "chr20", "chr21", "chr22"), class = "factor"), 
    start = c(19068972, 25996369, 235879265, 46650500, 57732485, 
    44224566, 127510071, 33694865, 2297266, 105108497, 35252252, 
    64633822, 125738394, 416309, 93636009, 50070191, 72389245, 
    36432660, 19608500, 31498612), stop = c(20068972L, 26996369L, 
    236879265L, 47650500L, 58732485L, 45224566L, 128510071L, 
    34694865L, 3297266L, 106108497L, 36267753L, 65633822L, 126754018L, 
    1416309L, 94636009L, 51070191L, 73389245L, 37432660L, 20608500L, 
    32498612L), Gene = c("KIAA0090", "ZNF593", "GPR137B", "MCFD2", 
    "ABHD6", "GUF1", "FBN2", "HMGA1", "GNA12", "LRP12", "GBA2", 
    "NRBF2", "ST3GAL4", "WNK1", "SOCS2", "DLEU2", "FADS6", "BPI", 
    "TRMT2A", "PISD")), .Names = c("Chr", "start", "stop", "Gene"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L,7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L))
```

And what I am trying to achieve is something like starting from 0 for each chromosome, redistribute the gene intervals in a way that there is equal space between each gene (and some space before the next gene):

```
out = structure(list(Chr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 17L, 20L, 22L, 22L), .Label = c("chr1", 
"chr2", "chr3", "chr4", "chr5", "chr6", "chr7", "chr8", "chr9", 
"chr10", "chr11", "chr12", "chr13", "chr14", "chr15", "chr16", 
"chr17", "chr18", "chr19", "chr20", "chr21", "chr22"), class = "factor"), 
    start = c(2000000, 4000000, 6000000, 2000000, 2000000, 
    2000000, 2000000, 2000000, 2000000, 2000000, 2000000, 
    2000000,2000000, 2000000, 4000000, 2000000, 2000000, 
    2000000, 2000000, 2000000), stop = c(3000000L, 5000000L, 
    7000000L, 3000000L, 3000000L, 3000000L, 3000000L, 
    3000000L, 3000000L, 3000000L, 3000000L, 3000000L, 3000000L, 
    3000000L, 5000000L, 3000000L, 3000000L, 3000000L, 3000000L, 
    3000000L), Gene = c("KIAA0090", "ZNF593", "GPR137B", "MCFD2", 
    "ABHD6", "GUF1", "FBN2", "HMGA1", "GNA12", "LRP12", "GBA2", 
    "NRBF2", "ST3GAL4", "WNK1", "SOCS2", "DLEU2", "FADS6", "BPI", 
    "TRMT2A", "PISD")), .Names = c("Chr", "start", "stop", "Gene"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L,7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L))
```

For this subset of data lets say with 1000000 base pairs in between, however the difficulty I am having is deciding how to choose this value. Do I split the circumference into the number of genes I have across all the chromosomes and try to find the right interval from that? Thank you for any suggestions!

-fra

Comment: Are you simply trying to draw these segments on the radius of a circle?  If so, perhaps the `chord` or `circlize` packages might be useful, if you don't use the connecting arcs.

Comment: Hi Bryan, yes I am using the circlize package, but using the data I have now there are a lot of empty spaces so I wanted to rearrange the start and end values of each gene so that the genes are evenly distributed across each section. Is there maybe a way to do this automatically in the package?

Comment: Hmmm... Does this sound right?  Each gene has a particular length, you don't want to mess with that.  But, you want consistent spacing between them, regardless of the absolute stop of one and start of another.  And you want each section (chromosome) to be of the same (arc) length.  If this is right, let us know.  Sounds like a normalization issue, but the consistent gap makes it more challenging..

Comment: Yes, it's correct that I am looking for consistent spacing between genes independent of their real start and stop positions (but keeping their real length), but I don't want each chromosome to be of the same length but actually to adapt to the genes it contains...so to start at the end of the last gene from the previous chromosome + some padding in between... Does that make sense? Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Do you want the gap consistent w/i a chromosome, or consistent over the whole diagram?  The first is more obvious to me, but I fear you want the 2nd!

Comment: Indeed I was hoping to find a solution using the gap consistent over the whole diagram just to make it more pleasant for the eye...but any suggestions would help immensely. The point would be to be able to visualise clearly all of the entries without confusing one gene with the other if the other gene follows closely...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66362/discussion-between-bryan-hanson-and-user971102).

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here is a partial answer that may give you the idea and allow you to complete the whole thing.  Note that my results are showing an overlap on chr1, but it may be my math. I will let you track that down as I'm not sure this is the solution you need and I can't test the plotting aspect.

```
# Focus on chr1, 20 as they have multiple genes
df2 <- df[c(1:3, 19:20),]

Norm <- function(chrom) { # run on one chromosome at a time
    start <- chrom$start
    stop <- chrom$stop
    totLength <- max(stop) - min(start) 
    # simple normalization & offset
    newSt <- start/totLength
    newSt <- newSt - min(newSt)
    newEnd <- stop/totLength
    newEnd <- newEnd - min(newSt)
    totMax <- max(newSt, newEnd)
    newSt <- newSt/totMax
    newEnd <- newEnd/totMax
    return(data.frame(start = newSt, stop = newEnd))
}

normAll <- function(df) {
    #chromLvls <- levels(df$Chr) # this would work except your example data is truncated
    # and some levels are  missing
    chromLvls <- unique(as.character(df$Chr))
    noChrom <- length(chromLvls)
    drop <- 1:nrow(df)
    for (i in 1:noChrom) {
        df2 <- subset(df, df$Chr == chromLvls[i])
        df2[,c(2,3)] <- Norm(df2)
        df <- rbind(df, df2)
        }
    df <- df[-drop,] # row no's are mangled, may not matter
 }

res <- normAll(df2)

addGapBtwGenes <- function(df, gap = 0.05) {
    # gap is a fraction on [0...1]
    # this acts on a subset composed of just one chromosome
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
        df$start[i] <- df$start[i] + (i-1)*gap
        df$stop[i] <- df$stop [i]+ (i)*gap
        # this denormalizes things but that probably doesn't matter
        }
    return(df)
    }

gapAllGenes <- function(df, gap = 0.05) {
    #chromLvls <- levels(df$Chr) # this would work except your example data is truncated
    # and some levels are  missing
    chromLvls <- unique(as.character(df$Chr))
    noChrom <- length(chromLvls)
    drop <- 1:nrow(df)
    for (i in 1:noChrom) {
        df2 <- subset(df, df$Chr == chromLvls[i])
        if (nrow(df2) == 1) { # no gap needed
           df <- rbind(df, df2)
           next
          }
        df2 <- addGapBtwGenes(df2, gap = gap)
        df <- rbind(df, df2)
        }
    df <- df[-drop,] # row no's are mangled, may not matter
 }

res2 <- gapAllGenes(res)
```

You could write a function called `addGapBtwChrom` to control this gap, unless the plotting software allows this anyway.

The above gives this for res:

```
      Chr      start       stop     Gene
6    chr1 0.00000000 0.08472237 KIAA0090
7    chr1 0.02924442 0.11396679   ZNF593
8    chr1 0.91527763 1.00000000  GPR137B
191 chr22 0.00000000 0.63413477   TRMT2A
201 chr22 0.36586523 1.00000000     PISD
```

and for res2:

```
       Chr      start      stop     Gene
61    chr1 0.00000000 0.1347224 KIAA0090
71    chr1 0.07924442 0.2139668   ZNF593
81    chr1 1.01527763 1.1500000  GPR137B
1911 chr22 0.00000000 0.6841348   TRMT2A
2011 chr22 0.41586523 1.1000000     PISD
```

Perhaps this is close to what you want. Re-reading some of your comments I see I made all chromsomes approximately the same length, but again, I'll wait to see what you think of any of it.

Comment: Thanks very much Bryan! The idea of normalisation is great! I am wondering whether I can get the results in the same units so I can get the exact same gene lengths as the original, maybe I can just multiply the start and stop by *100000000? I haven't yet understood why the regions seem to be overlapping in the results while there is no overlap in the initial data, I am trying now by normalising only the start position and then adding the exact length of the original gene to that..but I don't think that is correct..

Comment: It's ripe for experimentation. To get back to the original relative lengths, you could stretch each chromosome, currently on a [0...1] scale, so that it is proportional to the original length. Actually, do it on the data with the gaps added.  How you go from here depends a lot of if you are trying to show semi-quant data or it needs to be super accurate.  But hopefully you have some ideas to go on from here.  Before too much more work, be sure you know what the input structures should be for `circulize` and also what plot options it provides, so you don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. The normalisation gives me overlapping regions, but if I remove these steps #newSt <- newSt - min(newSt) and newEnd <- newEnd - min(newSt), it works, but the chromosomes are not normalised anymore I guess because they are not [0..1]...

Comment: Those lines cause the starting point to be zero, so they create an offset, but they need the other lines in that function to give a sensible answer.   However, there might be completely different way to go about this.  Also, the order in which you do some of these things is critical.  Have fun.

Comment: Ok sorry this is not what I was looking for because it results in gene lengths being stretched, so for example if there is only one gene in the region it stretches over to cover the whole region. I would like the lengths to stay the same but just the start and stop positions to change so that there is no gap between genes... then maybe normalisation is not the answer...Thank you for your help though, it was good learning how to do this anyway!

Comment: So much of any problem is conceptualizing it properly, which sometimes takes a few iterations!  How about this: use the raw data, but close the gap between genes to a fixed distance, the gap.  To do this, you need to offset the start of genes 2...n but the correction changes each time you fix one (clever indexing needed).  Then, if you want each chromosome segment to be the same length in the plot, normalize as I had it in my answer.  Then you won't need the functions which add a gap.  In this case, a chromosome with many genes will appear to have smaller gaps, but that may be good visually.